# Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website for my computer studies class. I made a form that, when submitted, inputs the information into a sentence, replacing the default words. It was working fine using "getElementByID" but when I tried to validate it with javascript, the page kept refreshing when i submitted. It wouldn't let you submit with empty boxes, but I can't stop it from refreshing when I submit info. This is my html:

```
<form method="post" style="padding: 0px 15px;">
What is your name?<br>
<input type='text' name="Name" id='userName' placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
How old are you?<br>
<input type='text' name="Age" id='userAge' placeholder="Age" required><br><br>

<input type="submit" onsubmit="getInfo()" value='Submit Information'/><br><br></form>

<p style="text-indent: 50px;">Welcome to the site <b id='Name'> friend</b>. You're <b id='Age'> 47</b> years old right?<br><br></p>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function getInfo(){
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = userName;

    var userAge = document.getElementById('userAge').value;
    document.getElementById('Age').innerHTML = userAge;

}


$("input[type='button']").click(function(e) {


});
```

Please help me stop it from refreshing

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes I am. It works for validating empty fields but I dont know why it refreshes when I submit

Comment: Your `getInfo()` function should return `false` to stop the page reloading.

Comment: e.preventDefault() inside your click handler function

Comment: yes add `event.preventDefault();` as Connor said faster than me.

Comment: I've tried that and I just tried it again but it seems to do nothing

Comment: also depending on the browser you're using, document.getElementById('Name') in your code may not work because you are referencing a 'name' attribute and using it in the ..ById method. if you want to select elements based on their 'name' attribute, use document.getElementsByName('Name');

Comment: if your end goal is to just get it working, i'd suggest you using jquery and the validation library

Comment: @NicholasGulley update te question.

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove the on submit inline event from the input type submit (with this updates it will not run but the code will be more clear).

2) Change your jquery selector for input type 'submit' because you don't have a input type button.

3) e.preventDefault() avoid the default behavior of an event. Add it.

4) execute getInfo on click event

```
$("input[type='submit']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getInfo();
});
```

Another way to do it is to change your input type to button, so, You need to care only about step 1 and 4;

```
$("input[type='button']").on('click', function(e) {
    getInfo();
});
```

In order to take adventage of the html5 validation (like required input) you can stop the form submission once the validations already executed in the submit event of the form like this:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getInfo();
});
```

Try it:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLexe240/)

```js
function getInfo(){
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = userName);

    var userAge = document.getElementById('userAge').value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('Age').innerHTML = userAge);
    
}


$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getInfo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form' method="post" style="padding: 0px 15px;">
What is your name?<br>
<input type='text' name="Name" id='userName' placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
How old are you?<br>
<input type='text' name="Age" id='userAge' placeholder="Age" required><br><br>

<input type="submit" value='Submit Information'/><br><br></form>

<p style="text-indent: 50px;">Welcome to the site <b id='Name'> friend</b>. You're <b id='Age'> 47</b> years old right?<br><br></p>
```

Comment: ..and remove the inline `onsubmit` event ;-)

Comment: Do you test the Fiddle?

Comment: I need the input type to be submit instead of button to use the "required" attribute in the form. Sorry, I originally had the input type as submit but I've read different things online for hours and tested a bunch of things. Nothing worked and I forgot to change it back before I posted my original code

Comment: nope. the fiddle isnt even validating the form when its empty for me.

Comment: yeah i was talking about your initial question, i will search a workaround for your other problem and update this.

Comment: still it doesnt seem to be working. can you post all the code i dont think the fiddle is working properly for me. the sentence wont change in it